# starting an ASP.NET MVC project with Visual Web Developer 2010

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-web-developer-2010

I have downloaded and installed Visual Web Developer 2010 Express and ASP.NET MVC 3.

When I start Web Developer and try to create a "web project" I can see a template for "Razor" projects but I can't see one for "MVC" projects.

Where do I get the templates from, and how do I install them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Razor is an MVC view engine.

Use a new Razor project - it is MVC.

Comment: That may well be the case, but I am looking for the templates. All the tutorial sites I read start off with a statement along the lines of "Start a new ASP MVC Web Application" template.

Comment: @BENBUNCoder - Yes. Just start with the Razor project. It is a new ASP.NET MVC Web Application.